# How to serialize value in JSON to a different field name in DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have to write an API in Django Rest Framework, which would receive the body in following format:

```json
{
    content_id = 123
    content = [{
        "from": "Content 1 From"
        "body": "Content 1 Body"
    }]
}
```

I have to write a serializer which can represent this data. Since `from` is reserved python keyword, I have to use a different name to represent this field. How do I represent this in serializer? Here is my current draft serializer:

```py
class ContentAPISerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    content_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    
    class ContentSerailizer(serializers.Serializer):
        from_field = serializers.CharField()
        body = serializers.CharField()

    content = serializers.ListSerializer(child=ContentSerializer)
```